# Batch processing with java command in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, java

I need to run the following command from [this link](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html),

```
java -Xmx5g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar:stanford-corenlp-models-3.7.0.jar:* edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref -coref.algorithm neural -file example_file.txt
```

but it only processes the first file in the directory I specify, even if I change `example_file.txt` to `*`. Is there any way I can use this java command to process all files in the folder? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in *; do
  echo java -Xmx5g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar:stanford-corenlp-models-3.7.0.jar:* edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref -coref.algorithm neural -file $i
done
```

This loops over every (non hidden) file in the current directory and `echo`es your `java` command with the file name as an argument to the `-file` option. To actually perform the action, remove `echo`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I try this in the terminal but it seems to only print out all the commands I need to execute, without actually executing them. I also try putting it in a bash file but it's the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you! Now it's running. Sorry for not being able to upvote :(